# migrate data from SQL Server to dBASE

Tags: sql-server-2012, visual-foxpro, dbase

my current app is using ASP.Net Core and using SQL Server as DBMS.
is it possible to migrate data into dBASE based application like Visual-FoxPro 9.0?
if yes then how i can do that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could use VFP and if "you really wanted to", you could migrate data to a VFP database.
However, it is better to keep the data in MS SQL Server database and use it from VFP. It is really simple to connect to MS SQL server database and do CRUD operations there from within VFP. Basically there are 3 methods you could choose from:

1. Remote Views (RV)
2. SQL Pass Through cursors (SPT)
3. CursorAdapter class

CursorAdapter is the latest historically and most advanced option. You could visit my blog for a starter (https://cetinbasoz.blogspot.com/)